# Is it possible to get a partial output of a fanout orchestration using Azure Durable Functions?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I'm throwing hundreds of activities and as I'm using a WhenAll I get the results after all activities have completed. But I was wondering if it is possible to get partial results when calling

```
durableClient.GetStatusAsync(instanceId).Output;
```

The code to wait for all activities:

```
await Task.WhenAll(activitiesTasks);
var resultsFromTasks = activitiesTasks.Select(x => x.Result);
return resultsFromTasks;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Fan-in/Fan-out intrinsically is process of computing a bunch of tasks Parallele and aggregating the results of each of them. As you said `await task.WhenAll(activitiesTasks);` will aggregate the results of the `activitiesTasks` array whose task are working Parallele.
- If you want to achieve partial result of the task before aggregation, then we can use the concept of sub-orchestrations. Here instead of tasks in the task array we call a separate orchestration function for a segment of task which will give us a partial answer.
- This sub-orchestration is implemented using `CallSubOrchestratorAsync` then we will store this in a list. But at last, we will call `task.WhenAll();`  for aggregation. Here we will pass the list of the orchestration.

Refer the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-sub-orchestrations?tabs=csharp) on Sub-orchestration.

Comment: What about querying the storage account history and getting those with TaskComplete or something on that sort to return partial results in another GetStatus function?